# PHP Timezone problem

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp

I am in Albuquerque, NM. I am trying to update some stamps every time I put an entry into a database.

Here is what I use.

```
date_default_timezone_set("US/Mountain");
$stamp =mktime();
//$stamp = gmmktime();
$time = date("H:i:s",$stamp);$date = date("Y-m-d",$stamp);
```

My local time is 12:15 PM but what I get is 18:15PM instead.

If you can see what's going wrong please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean that you get 18:15 for the value of `$time`, or that 18:15 is what shows up inside your database?

Comment: Thanks! I need to be more attentive, I had a problem at the node where   the application insert and entry into the database. The time that I used there was UTC.

Comment: That's why I prefer to keep the timezone info in the textual representation where ever possible.

Comment: Currently you have two separate strings like `2010-04-1` and `10:07:15`. And they have different meanings in different timezones. Compare that to a string like `2010-04-18T12:44:43-0600`. It doesn't matter if you had (mistakenly) used the utc timezone instead, since the offset is included. The resulting string `2010-04-18T18:44:43-0000` still represents the same point in time. And btw: maybe you don't have to convert the date/time values in php, maybe your database can do that for you. But that depends on he dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"My local time is 12:15 PM but what I get is 18:15PM instead."
6 hours ...that's the offset between UTC and American/Mountain, 18:00 in your local timezone is 12:00 UTC.
What does

```
$rc = date_default_timezone_set("US/Mountain");
$stamp =mktime();
echo 'version: ', phpversion(), "\n";
echo 'rc=', var_dump($rc);
echo 'stamp: ', $stamp, "\n";
echo 'time(): ', time(), "\n";
echo 'date: ', date(DateTime::ISO8601, $stamp), "\n";
echo 'gmdate: ', gmdate(DateTime::ISO8601, $stamp), "\n";
```

print?

Comment: version: 5.2.13
rc=bool(true) 
stamp: 1271616283 
time(): 1271616283 
date: 2010-04-18T12:44:43-0600  (AHA!)
gmdate: 2010-04-18T18:44:43+0000

Isn't this what I try to do in essence?

Comment: Yes it is. And the output looks fine. So my bets right now are on "the code you've posted is not the code you've tested." ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try date_default_timezone_set("America/Denver");

Comment: I don't think this would make a difference.  While `America/Denver` is preferred over `US/Mountain`, the latter is still valid (for now). See http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

Comment: Is it possible you're using php < 5.1 and the date_default_timezone_set function doesn't exist?

Comment: then a fatal "undefined function" would occur.